# HTML5/JS geolocation show only posts from a certain radius

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, radius

Hey I really tried to search the internet for any small tips to try to solve my dilemma but, yet I still havent found anything about it and I feel bad for asking for annoying help but I just dont really know javascript, but it is needed.

So basically, Im making this thing and it requires the user to give the geolocation and then it would only show posts made from users in a certain radius(5-10mi). Would this need to store location in a database? or would this be something I'm not aware of?

All help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance :)

Comment: Where are these posts you want to display? It sounds like they're probably in a database and you want to filter the posts returned from the database, but then it sounds unlikely it would be a JS issue. If that is correct, then do you have the geo-location for each post stored in the DB?

Comment: Well I guess that isnt a JS issue but im confused on how I can control who can see it if the person is in a radius of where the post location is, kinda yik-yakish

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't know what's in the backend of your website, but I believe this should work if you're using MySQL and have the geolocation of each post stored in the database. If another type of database, then this may vary slightly.

```
SELECT *, ( 3960 * acos( cos( radians( @custLat ) ) *
  cos( radians( Lat ) ) * cos( radians(  Lng  ) - radians( @custLng ) ) +
  sin( radians( @custLat ) ) * sin( radians(  Lat  ) ) ) ) AS Distance
FROM Posts
WHERE Distance < 10
```

Where @custLat and @custLng are the variable co-ordinates of the user. Lat and Lng are the fields of the database table in which we have stored the post co-ordinates.

This and more is detailed at https://www.stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/development/code-snippets/the-haversine-formula-in-c-and-sql/

Note: I've not tested this.